# Netsuite PHP API - Find customer by email

Tags: php, soap, netsuite

I am trying to search for a customer by email. The Netsuite api documentation does not help much. Appreciate any help i can get. Thank You.

```
    global $myNSclient;
$email = "myemail";
$item = new nsComplexObject('SearchStringField');
$item->setFields(array( 'searchValue' => $email, 'operator' => 'is'));
$search = new nsComplexObject('ContactSearchBasic');
$search->setFields($item);
$myNSclient->setSearchPreferences(false, 10);
$searchResponse = $myNSclient->search($search);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got quite a few gray hairs trying to figure this out myself.

Below is the code to get a contact (different than a customer in Netsuite, both are native data types though) from their email.  It will be very similar for a Customer.

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 20);

$recordRef = new RecordRef();
$recordRef->internalId = '-6'; //Internal ID for a customer is -2, contact is -6

$contactSearch = new ContactSearch(); //use CustomerSearch() for a customer
$contactSearchBasic = new ContactSearchBasic();//SearchRecordBasic
$contactSearchBasic->email = new SearchStringField();
$contactSearchBasic->email->searchValue = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$contactSearchBasic->email->operator = SearchStringFieldOperator::is;
$contactSearch->basic = $contactSearchBasic;

$searchRequest = new searchRequest(); //% contains a searchRecord
$searchRequest->searchRecord = $contactSearch; 

$searchResponse = $service->search($searchRequest);
```